# Changing a DateTime field to a Timestamp field when an application is running in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, odp.net

I am using Oracle 11 (64 bit) with Oracle.DataAccess (ODP.NET) 4.1.

I have a table with a date field;

```
create table x (..., y date, ...);
```

Also an application bulk inserting to this table;

```
var bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(connection) { DestinationTableName = "x" };
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
```

When I run following DDL;

```
ALTER TABLE x MODIFY (y timestamp );
```

and start the application then everything is in place and the timestamp field is populated properly (we can see minutes, seconds and milliseconds in the field value);

`2016-03-07 06:04:34.456`

etc.

The problem is when the aplication is running and the DDL is run, bulk inserted fields loose their time part. They becomes something like

`2016-03-07 00:00:00.000`.

Meaning, when the field is date and when application is running then when the following DDL is run;

```
ALTER TABLE x    MODIFY (y timestamp );
```

all newly inserted fields loose their time parts.

Why do you think it behaves like this?

NOTE: Oracle returns following version text;

```
select * from v$version;




Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Comment: You execute a `ALTER TABLE ...` statement at run-time of your application? This does not look very smart to me, you should revise you database, resp. application design.

Comment: The problem is we cannot stop the application and it is being used actively. But we need the millisecond values and Oracle date column does not hold milliseconds. If the application is restarted no problem there.

Comment: What is the .net data type in the `table` for the Date column?  is that being truncated or even populated with a date/time?

Comment: It is a .Net DateTime with millisecond values and it is populated. We tested it with a fresh started application.

Comment: So reading your question again, you are performing your bulk insert then changing the column type to a timestamp?  This won't work because if your source column is a DATE without time, converting the column can't create a time from no data.  Also FYI I have an oracle table with a DATE column which shows the time?

Comment: Hello again. Bulk importing is continuous. In any time if I change a date column to a timestamp column, subsequent imports are inserted without time parts. If I revert timestamp back to date then subsequent imports are inserted OK.  This is the case when the application is still running. The main idea is I need to convert the column to timestamp, while application is running, to see  millisecond values. But if I do that time part of the column dissepears completely, no hours, no minutes no seconds. Only day value.